# API call from azure databricks notebook to splunk

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My query is that lets say I connect to a VDI and then access a clients azure environment. From there I need to make an Rest API call to other on prem or cloud hosted systems such as splunk, cmdb - service now. I am not able to directly call the API in python notebook. Is there any configuration required in Azure first to do so?

I tried directly calling the API using import requests but not able to do so. I think the system doesnot recognize the api call from azure as a trusted one.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your Azure Databricks workspace from on-prem or instances outside Azure by following the steps below:-

You can follow this Document to create your Azure Databricks inside a V-NET :-

[Deploy Azure Databricks in your Azure virtual network (VNet injection) - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject)

I deployed an Azure Databricks V-NET from the template in the document above for V-NET injection with Network security group to allow inbound and outbound access to Azure Databricks workspace.

Create one Network Security group and copy its resource ID in the template for deployment, Like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Azure Databricks V-NET got created successfully like below:-

[image]

Now Deploy your Azure Databricks Workspace inside the V-NET like below:-

[image]

[image]

Databricks Workspace deployed like below:-
You can enable Public Network Access for your azure Databricks to be accessible to your On-prem or Splunk or other cloud instances with NSG Rules:-

[image]

In NSG Rules, Make sure you allow your VDI's or other cloud's, SPLUNK API's IP as an inbound and outbound rule:-

Inbound connection from your VDI, on-prem or Splunk hosted  API's to Azure services or Databricks.

[image]

Outbound rule to allow Azure Databricks to reach the destination systems, Make sure you allow Outbound connections to your VDI and other Cloud hosted API's from azure.

[image]

Create a VPN connection from your On-prem or other Cloud Site to Azure and then configure virtual network gateway transit to Azure Databricks Workspace like below:-

Create a VPN and use the same Virtual network gateway as your VPN connection from your On-prem, cloud instances to Azure Site:-

[image]

Associated Azure Virtual Network gateway to the same V-NET as the Azure Databricks workspace, If the V-NET gateway is in different V-NET than Azure Databricks V-NET, you can configure V-NET peering and configure user defined routes.

Additionally, Allow your on-prem, cloud hosted firewall to access Azure Databricks URL below:-

> *.azuredatabricks.net for Azure Public
>
> *.databricks.azure.us for Azure Government
>
> https://adb1666506161514800.0.azuredatabricks.net for your azure
> databricks workspace only

**References:-**

[Connect your Azure Databricks workspace to your on-premises network - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network)

[Configure domain name firewall rules - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/network/firewall-rules?source=recommendations)

[Tutorial - Connect an on-premises network and a virtual network: S2S VPN: Azure portal - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal)